# HDMI audio not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, hdmi

I have installed pulse audio control and configured Nvidia output profile. When audio is played, it shows something is playing under Nvidia profile but still cannot hear any sound. Can I make this output default?
[image]

Do I need to make any changes to the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on lubuntu 18.04.
I needed to change to the corresponding output under configuration tab.